# Sharing a Redis instance with password protection on cAdvisor

Tags: docker, redis, cadvisor

I’m sharing an instance of Redis on a docker instance between Authelia and cAdvisor.
In a security audit it was flagged that not using a password on Redis was a high risk. The documentation for adding a password to Redis is fine as is getting Authelia to use the password to access Redis but I can’t find any environment variables or other methods of telling cAdvisor to use a password. Is this possible please?

Searching cAdvisor GitHub doesn’t seem to have any info on this.